# LINQ on a DataTable IN a CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, linq, stored-procedures, clr

does anybody know if it's possible (and how) to use LINQ on a DataTable **inside a CLR Stored Procedure**?

I have no problems using LINQ on a DataTable in a standard WinForms proj however; I'm using a Database Project in VS2010 on SQL2005 and creating a Stored Procedure:

(simplified listing)

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void ProcessReOrder()
{       
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) { 
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("database.dbo.OtherSp", conn);  
        DataTable table = new DataTable("ReOrder");
        adapter.Fill(table);

        var query = from t in table.AsEnumerable() 
                    where t.Field<int>("Id") > 1000 select t.Field<int>("Id");

    etc.....
}
```

The **problem** is, AsEnumerable() is an extension method and although I've got the *using* reference to LINQ; it still isn't found.

Searching Google, has lead me to believe this is to do with using an LINQ Entity reference (DLL) buried in the framework however, as this is a DB Project, we don't get to add references to any DLL on the system; the add reference box is restricted to a select few assemblies and there isn't a *browse...* button.

Regardless of performance issues etc, I don't *want* to hand roll a lot of ADO/T-SQL inside my .NET Stored proc; i prefer LINQ and the ability to move the code to different layers/DB Platforms. Is LINQ on a DataTable inside a Stored Proc supported (i guessing not) or am I completely off base here and must code with T-SQL?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write your own `AsEnumerable` method? It's a one-liner:  `foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows) yield return r;`  By the way, `AsEnumerable` is in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Comment: If you use an ORM like LINQ-TO-SQL or Entity Framework you can add Stored procedures and call them like a method call.

Comment: @mquander, I suspected this would be my only option. I'm trying not to re-code parts of MS' LINQ implementation but use it "as is" - Especially as the code works without an additional impl outside of a CLR Stored Procedure.
You're right, its not the Entity namespace but the System.Data.DataSetExtensions (my mistake), only can't reference that DLL from a DB Project. Looks as though MS will only let you use assy's that are deployed on the SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: @alastair, We already use ORM in other tier's. Here, I'm simply looking to use C# and LINQ (for Objects) instead of TSQL for a Stored Proc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this will get you all the way there, however this will get **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** installed into SQL Server 2008 so you can reference it from your SQL CLR project.  Note that I was logged in as a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role.

First, I had to get the database prepared to load the unsafe assembly. I executed `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;` then I set the owner of the database to *sa* with `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON database::dbname TO sa;`.

Next, I extracted v3.5 of the assembly from the GAC on my workstation by copying the file to a holding directory (say c:\temp) from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089.

I was then able to install the assembly with the statement `CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Data.DataSetExtensions] FROM 'C:\temp\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;`.

You'll receive this friendly reminder when the statement completes: *Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.data.datasetextensions, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.*

At this point, I was then able to reference **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** in my SQL CLR project, and I confirmed that `AsEnumerable()` showed up on the DataTable instance.